# Add variable into array in php

Tags: php

I want to store all unique inside the combination without repetition on a bigger array. How should I do. I have facing some problem with this code. Please help me.

```
foreach( $combination as $value )
    {

     if($sourceip!=$value)

    array_push($combination, $sourceip);

    }
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Perhaps you are looking for `in_array()` without a loop?

Comment: perhaps you could just use `array_unique()` ?

Answer (score 2):

If `$sourceip` isn't an object you should be able to do so via [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if (!in_array($sourceip, $combination))
    array_push($combination, $sourceip);
```

Comment: From the [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) docs, its better to use `$combination[] = $sourceip;` if you are just pushing one element since it avoids the overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$combination` are all values and you want to store values unique in the array `$unique`:

```
foreach ($combination as $value) {
  if (!in_array($value, $unique) {
    $unique[] = value;
  }
}
```